# Output didn't include all of the characters

Tags: c, string, char

I was trying to input a string of characters and only output the last and the first character respectively. Below is the code I'm using.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        int n; // length of the string
        char string[101];

        scanf("%d %s", &n, &string);
        fflush(stdin); // sometimes I also use getchar();

        printf("%c%c", string[n+1], string[0]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using for loop because i wanted to input the string 3 times, but when I ran the code the input isn't what I expected. If I input e.g.

```
5 abcde
```

output

```
 a //there's space before the a
```

can you help me tell where I've gone wrong?

input:

```
5 abcde
6 qwerty
3 ijk
```

excpeted output:

```
ea
yq
ki
```

Comment: Arrays in C use 0-based indexing. So if the string has 5 characters, the last character is `string[4]`.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin) about `fflush(stdin)`.

Comment: Rather than allowing the user to lie to you about how long the string is (either accidentally or on purpose), you should use `strlen(string)` to find the actual length of the string.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few problems in your code:

In this statement

```
scanf("%d %s", &n, &string);
```

you don't need to give `&` operator with `string`. An array name, when used in an expression, converts to pointer to first element (there are few *exceptions* to this rule). Also, the size of `string` array is `101` characters but if you provide input more than `101` characters, the `scanf()` end up accessing `string` array beyond its size. You should restrict the `scanf()` to not to read more than `100` characters in `string` array when input size is more than that. (keep the remain one character space is for null terminating character that `scanf()` adds). For this, you can provide width modifier in the format specifier - `%100s`.

You are not validating the string length input against the input string from user. What happen, if the input string length is greater than or less than the actual length of input string!

`fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour because, as per standard, `fflush` can only be used with output streams.

> *I was trying to input a string of characters and only output the last and the first character respectively.*

For this, you don't need to take the *length of the string* as input from user. Use standard library function - `strlen()`. This will also prevent your program from the problems that can occur due to erroneous length input from user, if that is not validated properly.

Putting these altogether, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
        char string[101];

        printf ("Enter string:\n");
        scanf("%100s", string);
        printf("Last character: %c, First character: %c\n", string[strlen(string) - 1], string[0]);

        int c;
        /*discard the extra characters, if any*/
        /*For e.g. if user input is very long this will discard the input beyond 100 characters */
        while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
            /* discard the character */;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that, `scanf(%<width>s, ......)` reads up to `width` or until the first whitespace character, whichever appears first. If you want to include the spaces in input, you can use the appropriate conversion specifier in `scanf()` or a better alternative is to use [fgets()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) for input from user.

Answer (score 0):

Line 11: string[n+1] -> string[n-1]

Comment: Thanks! I already changed it and it worked.